# O que é Fog computing?

Tags: terminologia, ciência-da-computação, sistemas-distribuídos, iot

O que seria esse termo Fog computing(Também conhecido como computação em neblina ou névoa) que é utilizado em alguns projetos IoT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente, é quando temos diversos dispositivos acessando a rede em posições "periféricas", sem serem grandes consumidores ou emissores de dados.

Um exemplo são os controladores de temperatura inteligentes, que aumentam ou abaixam a temperatura baseando-se em previsões de tempo e clima, requerindo, assim, um acesso à internet. Porém tais emissores não precisam de conexões rápidas e estáveis, já que não vão processar quantidades grandes de dados, como páginas web.

Com o avanço da computação em nuvem, é provável que a "névoa" se torne muito maior que é hoje, englobando diversos elementos de nossa vida cotidiana, como cafeteiras, geladeiras e outros eletrodomésticos. Note que não mencionei carros, pois a tendência dos veículos automotivos é, provavelmente, o uso de grandes quantias de dados, através de posicionamento e localização via satélite, além dos "carros autônomos", requerindo, com isso, o processamento de um grande volume de dados, assim como uma provável conexão entre um e outro.

Recomendo os [cursos sobre internet das coisas da Samsung](http://www.codeiot.org.br/) para melhor compreensão do tema.